# Orthogonailty with PHP development

Tags: php, coding-style

I am reading the "Pragmatic Programmer", I am at the section were they talk about "Orthogonailty" and the approach to take when coding. I was wondering if you can implement the "Orthogonailty" technique with PHP application development because in the book its mainly about software development?

Do you know of any articles which talk about PHP and "Orthogonailty" or does any one have a view on this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Orthogonality" is a term copied from [linear algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality): saying "x and y are orthogonal" means "x is perpendicular to y".

In the case of software development, two orthogonal parts of a system may be varied independently without impacting the other. In particular, the implication is that parts of a system are orthogonal when, as you make changes in one part, side effects of your changes don't affect other parts.

Comment: I understand the concept of "Orthogonality" but I am unsure if I can use this approach in php development. Do you have any thought's on this ?

Comment: I'm paging through that chapter at the moment. There's nothing particular about PHP: you can apply the concept (or not) as easily in Java, Smalltalk, or whatever.

Comment: I should add: there is some talk about bringing Traits into PHP: http://wiki.php.net/rfc/horizontalreuse

Comment: @Frank Shearar, I have been re-reading the book and it just got me thinking if I could use the concept with php dev. I don't actually see any way, I think at a push you could maybe implement it with Javascript, What do you think ?

Comment: What is it about PHP that you think will not allow you to apply the principle of orthogonality?

Comment: I think I might be getting the wrong idea, Would the use of one database connection and requring the database connection on each page with need's it be a type of "orthogonality" ?

Answer (score 2):

Orthogonality is a language-agnostic concept. Well, unless you're coding in BASIC or something equally obsolete. Not only is PHP capable of of achieving it, but so can any modern language. You could google it if you're looking for more information, but basically what it stands for is "don't write spaghetti code".

If you're worried about it, I'd recommend a strict OO approach in PHP with at least some sort of MVC separation. For more information on those you might want to consider going through Code Complete and Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software.